# Installing ADAM on Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, adam

I'm currently tasked with moving a Web Application that uses Active Directory Application Management (ADAM) from a 2003 server to a 2012 Server.  My question more about any references to install ADAM on Windows 2012.  The reference I am  going off of is for Windows Server 2003 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739247(v=WS.10).aspx)

I'm wondering if anyone could guide me to some documentation on how to install ADAM on 2012?

**UPDATE:**

I found an application called Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard.  By running that will I get an ADAM instance?

Comment: See serverfault.com/help/on-topic.  Why don't you try it, and ask a question if you run into problems?

Comment: @FalconMomot - I just found the AD LDS Wizard as I mentioned and I went through it.  Now my question is, is there a GUI that shows me the ADAM instance I created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you (correctly) guessed, AD LDS is the new name of the software previously known as ADAM; it's no longer a separate product: now it's built-in in the Windows Server OS, and you only need to enable it as you would do with any other server role.

Here's the relavant documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831593.aspx.

Caveat: there is no guarantee that an application built to work with ADAM will necessarily and seamlessly work with AD LDS; you should ask the developer(s) for guidance here.

Comment: I am the developer on this one as well.  I inherited this application and have never done any ADAM work previously.  Can you tell me where I would find the GUI to see the instance I installed?

Comment: Check the documentation in the link; everything is explained there.